# Does there exist a non-zero module over $R$ which vanishes modulo a nilpotent ideal?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a *noetherian* ring, $I$ a nilpotent ideal in $R$, and $M$ a module over $R$, of *infinite* type, such that $M/IM = 0$. Is it necessarily the case that $M=0$?

If $M$ were of finite type, then we would immediately get a positive answer by Nakayama's Lemma. If $R$ is not noetherian, then I think I have a counterexample.

Comment: It is true even if $R$ is not Noetherian.  Maybe in that case you are thinking that $I$ is not nilpotent but merely consists of nilpotent elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as Eric Wofsey points out, it is necessarily the case that $M=0$, and this is in fact true even if $R$ is not Noetherian! Since $I$ is nilpotent, let $n$ be such that $I^n=0$. Now, since $M\big/IM=0$, we have in other words that $M=IM$. By induction on $k$, we then have $M=I^kM$ for all $k$, whence in particular $M=I^nM=0$.

Perhaps instead, again as Eric points out, you are thinking of a [*nil*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nil_ideal) ideal; this is an ideal in which every element is nilpotent. Now, if $R$ is Noetherian, then every nil ideal of $R$ is nilpotent. Indeed, if $I\leqslant R$ is any ideal, then, since $R$ is Noetherian, we have $I=\langle a_1,\dots,a_n\rangle$ for some $a_i\in R$. If $I$ is also nil, then for each $i\leqslant n$ there exists $k_i$ such that $a_i^{k_i}=0$. Let $k=\sum_{i=1}^nk_i$; can you show that $I^k=0$? In particular, by the paragraph above, the answer to your question is still yes even if "nilpotent" is replaced by "nil".

However, it is the case that the generalized statement does *not* hold in general if $R$ is not Noetherian. For example, let $R$ be the quotient $$\frac{\mathbb{Q}[x_n:n\in\mathbb{N}]}{\langle x_1^2,x_n-x_{n+1}^2:n\in\mathbb{N}\rangle}.$$ For convenience, denote the image of each $x_n$ in $R$ as $a_n$, and let $I$ be the ideal of $R$ generated by the $a_n$. We have $I^2=I$, ie $I\big/I^2=0$, since $a_n=a_{n+1}^2\in I^2$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Furthermore, by induction, we have $a_n^{2^{n}}=0$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, so $I$ is generated by nilpotent elements and hence (why?) nil. But $I\neq 0$, so taking $M=I$ gives the desired counterexample.